# Spam detection/Spam filter system in Java

Tags: java, spam, spam-prevention

I've built a private messaging system on a site, and I want to implement a spam filter, preferably in Java.

So ... I'm interested if there a Java library implementing this already, or if I have to start building my own. What I found so far is this Bayesian Filtering: http://www.shiffman.net/teaching/a2z/bayesian/

Are there any other good Java libraries??

What do you recommend me?

Thanks

PS: the system is using private messages between site members and is not an email system.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of spam. Bayesian is good against off-topic messages, but if the spam is very similar to legit messages, you might want to set up some sort of sender reputation. The way SO works is a good example; you need to earn points by participating before you can use the more powerful features of the site. This could be subverted if spammers were to somehow break into the computers of high-rep users, or otherwise manage to hijack their reputation.